# Laravel getting data from the database in .js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I need to change the series values ​​in the .js file by pulling data from the database, how can I do this? @php not working in js file

_wChartTwo.28581ae9.js file:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){try{let s=sessionStorage.getItem("theme");if(JSON.parse(s).settings.layout.darkMode){var o="dark";Apex.tooltip={theme:o};var a={chart:{type:"donut",width:370,height:430},colors:["#622bd7","#e2a03f","#e7515a","#e2a03f"],dataLabels:{enabled:!1},legend:{position:"bottom",horizontalAlign:"center",fontSize:"14px",markers:{width:10,height:10,offsetX:-5,offsetY:0},itemMargin:{horizontal:10,vertical:30}},plotOptions:{pie:{donut:{size:"75%",background:"transparent",labels:{show:!0,name:{show:!0,fontSize:"29px",fontFamily:"Nunito, sans-serif",color:void 0,offsetY:-10},value:{show:!0,fontSize:"26px",fontFamily:"Nunito, sans-serif",color:"#1ad271",offsetY:16,formatter:function(t){return t}},total:{show:!0,showAlways:!0,label:"Total",color:"#888ea8",formatter:function(t){return t.globals.seriesTotals.reduce(function(n,e){return n+e},0)}}}}}},stroke:{show:!0,width:15,colors:"#0e1726"},series:[985,737,270],labels:["Apparel","Sports","Others"],responsive:[{breakpoint:1440,options:{chart:{width:325}}},{breakpoint:1199,options:{chart:{width:380}}},{breakpoint:575,options:{chart:{width:320}}}]}}else{var o="dark";Apex.tooltip={theme:o};var a={chart:{type:"donut",width:370,height:430},colors:["#622bd7","#e2a03f","#e7515a","#e2a03f"],dataLabels:{enabled:!1},legend:{position:"bottom",horizontalAlign:"center",fontSize:"14px",markers:{width:10,height:10,offsetX:-5,offsetY:0},itemMargin:{horizontal:10,vertical:30}},plotOptions:{pie:{donut:{size:"75%",background:"transparent",labels:{show:!0,name:{show:!0,fontSize:"29px",fontFamily:"Nunito, sans-serif",color:void 0,offsetY:-10},value:{show:!0,fontSize:"26px",fontFamily:"Nunito, sans-serif",color:"#0e1726",offsetY:16,formatter:function(e){return e}},total:{show:!0,showAlways:!0,label:"Total",color:"#888ea8",formatter:function(e){return e.globals.seriesTotals.reduce(function(i,l){return i+l},0)}}}}}},stroke:{show:!0,width:15,colors:"#fff"},series:[985,737,270],labels:["Apparel","Sports","Others"],responsive:[{breakpoint:1440,options:{chart:{width:325}}},{breakpoint:1199,options:{chart:{width:380}}},{breakpoint:575,options:{chart:{width:320}}}]}}var r=new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-2"),a);r.render(),document.querySelector(".theme-toggle").addEventListener("click",function(){let t=sessionStorage.getItem("theme");JSON.parse(t).settings.layout.darkMode?r.updateOptions({stroke:{colors:"#0e1726"},plotOptions:{pie:{donut:{labels:{value:{color:"#bfc9d4"}}}}}}):r.updateOptions({stroke:{colors:"#fff"},plotOptions:{pie:{donut:{labels:{value:{color:"#0e1726"}}}}}})})}catch(s){console.log(s)}});
```

analytics.blade file:

```
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 layout-spacing">
            <x-widgets._w-chart-two title="Sales by Category"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue. Fellow these steps:
in Laravel controller method:

```
// Specify the path to the JavaScript file you want to edit
$jsFilePath = 'path/to/your/javascript/file.js';

// Read the content of the JavaScript file into a variable
$jsContent = file_get_contents($jsFilePath);

// Make your desired changes to the JavaScript content
// For example, let's replace a string in the JavaScript code
$oldString = 'Hello, World!';
$newString = 'Hello, OpenAI!';
$jsContent = str_replace($oldString, $newString, $jsContent);

// Write the updated content back to the JavaScript file
file_put_contents($jsFilePath, $jsContent);

echo "JavaScript file updated successfully.";
```